# Launching PHPUnit in PHPStorm for a single instance

Tags: yii, phpunit, phpstorm

I've seen a lot topics about PhpStorm, but they actually got me more confused than I was before.
Basically, my file structure looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nFE2.png
(This is from the Yii 1.1.13 Demo App "Blog")

Now what I want to do is to have these two options:

1. Choose any of these files -> Right click -> Run (as PHPUnit).
   bootstrap.php and phpunit.xml have to be loaded somehow, because
   these specify where to load the (Yii) classes needed.
2. run all tests
       within a directory (including subdirectories).

Could anyone point out how to edit the run configuration to achieve this? I already managed to run single tests but the configuration for them were more complicated than to just run them from command line.

Software used:
OS: Mac OS 10.7 Lion, PHPStorm 6, Yii 1.1.13 and PHPUnit 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your PHPUnit configuration and bootstrap file in the project settings (PHP -> PHPUnit). Now whenever your run a single test, testcase, directory etc. PHPStorm will use your bootstrap.

Comment: But how to run a single test? When I choose "Run" I first have to create a "Run as PHPUnit"-configuration. In the first section "Test Runner" I have to pick a Test Scope and I'm not sure what to pick. Also I'm not sure what "Share" and "Single instance only" in the right corner do.

Comment: I can just right click on a test method name and click run. PHPStorm will automaticaly create a run configuration and run your test.

Comment: Where do you click? And is it just "Run" or "Run as PHPUnit"? Because the auto created configs are always for "PHPScript" and not "PHPUnit". (If I right click on a file and choose "Run".)

Comment: I only have option run. On run a submenu come up with 2 options. 'testTestName' and 'testTestName on server'. I click the first one. My PHPStorm version is 5.0.4, but I'm pretty sure in PHPStorm 6 it's the same as I use that one at work. You must choose 'Run as PHPUnit' I think.

Comment: Thank you. The files under /unit are working now. The ones in /functional are not. They are not recognized as PHPUnit files by PHPStorm. (See different icons.) I guess this is because the files in /functional extend WebTestCase, which Phpstorm/Php/Phpunit can't find.

Comment: Seems like some kind of circle. PHPStorm doesn't recognize it as PHPUnit -> bootstrap.php and phpunit.xml don't get loaded -> (C)WebTestCase doesn't get included -> PHPStorm can't recognize it's actually a PHPUnit test. Does anyone know how to break this circle?

Comment: Do your test classes in functional end with 'Test'? And which PHPStorm version are you using?

Comment: I use PHPStorm 6.0 And yes, they all end with "Test". Let's take CommentTest for example (see file structure). CommentTest (CommentTest.php) extends WebTestCase (../WebTestCase.php; also seen in the screenshot) which extends CWebTestCase (should be found via bootstrap.php) which extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase (should be found in include_path via PHPUnit). However, it doesn't get recognized as a test in the first place. So when I choose "Run" it runs as PHP Script (instead of PHPUnit), and nothing get included.

Comment: 'found via bootstrap' is not enough. CWebTestCase should be indexed by PHPStorm to be detected as a unit test. You can check that by doing CTRL + Left mouse click, if your are not directed to the file you'll know it is not indexed. You have to include the library (where CWebTestCase resides) in your project or add the library to the include_path (you can do that via the PHPStorm settings).

Comment: CWebTestcase IS found. It is hard to describe which class inherits which. Maybe it is best to take a look at the Yii classes: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/tree/master/framework/test. In my folders /unit all extend CDbTestCase (which works fine), and in /functional all extend WebTestCase (which then extends CWebTestCase; this doesn't work). Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you any further. If all used libraries are indexed correctly and your testcase extends `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` in the top of the inheritance tree you should be able to run the tests without problems. Last suggestion; try extending your functional tests from `CWebTestCase` instead of `WebTestCase`, to eliminate that the problem is in your custom `WebTestCase` class.

Comment: Ultimately CWebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase not PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase. However I put /usr/lib/php/pear/PHPUnit (this is where my PHPUnit .php files are stored) in the include_path in PHPStorm. (Settings -> PHP -> Include path and then "+"). Thanks for your help, everything working fine now.

Comment: Glad you got it working. In the end it's always something simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yii, your test classes probably extend from CDbTestCase or CTestCase. PHPStorm does not know that these are tests cases, therefore it doesn't run them with PHPUnit automatically as it should with other tests cases.

What you need to do is setup Yii Framework in your PHP Include Path. You can access this menu by going to External Libraries in the left column of PHPStorm where you see your files. Once you add Yii to your projects PHP Include Path you will see the test files icon changes and has a red and green play like icon.

This means that you will be able to run them and PHPStorm will use your PHPUnit configuration to do so.

For more detailed information on how to configure phpunit with phpstorm check this article: 
http://trickortip.com/825/programming/php/phpunit-vagrant-vm-remote-php-interpreter-phpstorm-mac.html/